# How to create temporary object with core model class

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, core-data

I'm new to `Core Data` and I'm having an issues with creating and then deleting objects. I am trying to download and parse a `JSON` feed from a web service, then compare the feed data to the data in the `Core Data` model. I have 2 models in the Core Data model: `RootBeer` & `Comments`. Being new, I figured that I could use the `RootBeer` class, like any other, in that I could initialize, then store data temporarily; however, that isn't the case. So then I created a new context for each of the root beers, and then tried to delete them, but it seems that it only deletes the information, rather than the object itself. When I do a fetch of Core Data, it returns an array with 8 objects that have `null` attributes, rather than a `null`.

My question is either A: What can I do to delete the object from the context; or,

B. What alternative would you suggest to accomplish temporary data for the sake of comparison? Would I be better off to create another `RootBeer` class that I use to house the data from the `JSON` feed?

Any suggestions or direction would be great!

Here is my code for creating the deleting the object:

```
//rootBeerList is JSON feed
for(NSDictionary* rootBeer in rootBeerList){
        //create moc to store temp root beer object
        NSManagedObjectContext* moc = [self managedObjectContext];
        RootBeer* mRoot = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"RootBeer" inManagedObjectContext:moc]; 
        mRoot.rootBeerName = [rootBeer objectForKey:@"Name"];
        mRoot.rootBeerBrewer = [rootBeer objectForKey:@"Brewer"];
        mRoot.rootBeerId = [rootBeer objectForKey:@"Id"];
        mRoot.rootBeerDescription = [rootBeer objectForKey:@"Description"];
        mRoot.rootBeerDetails = [rootBeer objectForKey:@"ProductDetails"];
        //mRoot.hasCaneSugar = [ rootBeer objectForKey:@"Sugar"];
        //mRoot.hasCaffeine = [ rootBeer objectForKey:@"Caffeine"];
        mRoot.rootBeerLocation = [ rootBeer objectForKey:@"Region"];
        mRoot.rootBeerRating = [ rootBeer objectForKey:@"avgRating"];
        mRoot.updatedAt = [rootBeer objectForKey:@"updatedAt"]; 


        NSLog(@"Name: %@", mRoot.rootBeerName);
        NSLog(@"Name: %@", mRoot.rootBeerBrewer);
        NSLog(@"Name: %@", mRoot.rootBeerId);
        NSLog(@"Name: %@", mRoot.rootBeerDescription);
        NSLog(@"Name: %@", mRoot.rootBeerDetails);
        NSLog(@"Caffeine: %@", mRoot.hasCaffeine);
        NSLog(@"Sugar: %@", mRoot.hasCaneSugar);
        NSLog(@"avgRating: %@", mRoot.rootBeerRating);
        NSLog(@"updatedAt: %@", mRoot.updatedAt);
        //add object to array
        [tempArray addObject:mRoot];
        //delete object
        [moc deleteObject:mRoot];
        //save changes
        if(![moc save:&error]){
            NSLog(@"Can't Delete! %@ %@", error, [error localizedDescription]);
        }

    }
```

One other issue I noticed is that even after I save the object to the temporary array, it is still deleted, and I don't know why

UPDATE:

```
2013-05-20 14:34:31.622 RootBeerRecorder[54904:c07] web Root LIst (
    "<RootBeer: 0x835d5b0> (entity: RootBeer; id: 0x835d610 <x-coredata:///RootBeer/tD0DD60D5-008D-49C0-AB9F-F1D035DBA0302> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<RootBeer: 0x81512d0> (entity: RootBeer; id: 0x81544f0 <x-coredata:///RootBeer/tD0DD60D5-008D-49C0-AB9F-F1D035DBA0303> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<RootBeer: 0x81543d0> (entity: RootBeer; id: 0x8153aa0 <x-coredata:///RootBeer/tD0DD60D5-008D-49C0-AB9F-F1D035DBA0304> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<RootBeer: 0x81545b0> (entity: RootBeer; id: 0x81545f0 <x-coredata:///RootBeer/tD0DD60D5-008D-49C0-AB9F-F1D035DBA0305> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<RootBeer: 0x8154680> (entity: RootBeer; id: 0x8153ca0 <x-coredata:///RootBeer/tD0DD60D5-008D-49C0-AB9F-F1D035DBA0306> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<RootBeer: 0x8154960> (entity: RootBeer; id: 0x813a470 <x-coredata:///RootBeer/tD0DD60D5-008D-49C0-AB9F-F1D035DBA0307> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<RootBeer: 0x8154810> (entity: RootBeer; id: 0x8153db0 <x-coredata:///RootBeer/tD0DD60D5-008D-49C0-AB9F-F1D035DBA0308> ; data: <fault>)",
    "<RootBeer: 0x7460280> (entity: RootBeer; id: 0x7460190 <x-coredata:///RootBeer/tD0DD60D5-008D-49C0-AB9F-F1D035DBA0309> ; data: <fault>)"
)
2013-05-20 14:34:31.623 RootBeerRecorder[54904:c07] core Root LIst (
)
2013-05-20 14:34:31.624 RootBeerRecorder[54904:c07] Created Root Beer: <RootBeer: 0x81549f0> (entity: RootBeer; id: 0x8154940 <x-coredata:///RootBeer/tD0DD60D5-008D-49C0-AB9F-F1D035DBA03010> ; data: {
    comments = nil;
    hasCaffeine = nil;
    hasCaneSugar = nil;
    isFavorite = nil;
    myRootBeerRating = 0;
    rootBeerBrewer = nil;
    rootBeerDescription = nil;
    rootBeerDetails = nil;
    rootBeerId = 0;
    rootBeerLocation = nil;
    rootBeerName = nil;
    rootBeerRating = nil;
    updatedAt = nil;
})
... this continues
```

Comment: are there any threads involved? if you writing the objects on a background thread and not passing the changes to the main thread moc that could explain some of what your seeing

Comment: No, I am only using one thread. I've also update the OP with the results of the output I'm seeing.

Comment: if you don't delete or save the new model object it should exist as long as the MOC it was created in is around. if its not saved though it won't persist beyond that time frame. it sounds like you probably want one moc for all of these objects, not a moc per RootBeer

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but I would just point out that the popular RestKit framework for iOS includes the ability to automatically synchronize data you're pulling from the network with CoreData -- not any use if you're trying to learn how this stuff works, but just thought I'd mention it in case the functionality is what you need.

Comment: @isaac, does that framework do what I'm trying to do for me?

Comment: @Blaine: Perhaps this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15902749/optimizing-this-core-data-request/15903062#15903062.

Comment: @Blaine Effectively, yes.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to do. You create objects and then delete them. Do you save some of them? Is it that you're trying to decide whether to create a new object? Or are you deleting every object after you create it?

Comment: @TomHarrington, I'm creating an object from the web service, then taking that object and comparing it to the core data object. Basically I'm trying to determine if the web service object has been updated, if it has, then I'm trying to update the core data object, otherwise, leave it. Does that make sense?

Comment: the object you save in tempArray and the object you deleted in coredata have the same address so technically when you delete it the memory you allocated will also be deleted and likewise it will be removed in your tempArray. Best solution is do a "Deep" copy of your object before you put it in the array

Comment: What is a "deep" copy?